# how to build an AD server menu and select a server

Tags: powershell, drop-down-menu

I am not sure how I can do this. I should be able to with PowerShell. I can get a list of AD servers with:

```
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' `
-Properties Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address |
Sort-Object -Property Operatingsystem |
Select-Object -Property Name,Operatingsystem,OperatingSystemVersion,IPv4Address
```

I want create a `DropDown list` of the servers found, select a single server, and then run a process on them. It would be nice to have a second `DropDown menu` with the commands I want to run. Some of the processes are rebooting servers, deleting files, moving files, unlocking files, etc.

I just want to ease my processes so I do not have to log into 94 servers and do a basic tasks when I can connect remotely and do it click of a button.

Comment: I doubt someone here will design a UI for you, you would first need to do some research on WinForms or WPF then start designing your UI and then if you find any trouble ask the question here with the UI code.

Comment: As above, there are plenty of sample WinForms scripts written in PowerShell around to copy and modify. Here's just one: https://theitbros.com/powershell-gui-for-scripts/

Comment: i do apologize if it sounded like i was asking someone to design it for me. My intention was to ask for where do i get good resources to create what I am asking for. I have been unsuccessful in finding somewhere that has an example of code similar to what I need.

Comment: Here you go https://sysadminemporium.wordpress.com/2012/11/27/powershell-gui-for-your-scripts-episode-2/

Comment: here is my powershell menu so far. It only has three commands right now. I did acquire the shell of the menu from elsewhere.

Comment: [void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Drawing") 
[void] [System.Reflection.Assembly]::LoadWithPartialName("System.Windows.Forms")  
Import-Module ActiveDirectory
$Form = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Form    
$Form.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(600,400)  
param (
    [Parameter(Mandatory=$true, HelpMessage="Computer Name",ValueFromPipeline=$true)] $ComputerName
)
############################################## Start functions

Comment: function procInfo {
$computer=$DropDownBox.SelectedItem.ToString() #populate the var with the value you selected
$pingResult=ping $computer | fl | out-string;
$outputBox.text=$pingResult
                     } #end procInfo

Comment: function delLogs {
$computer=$DropDownBox.SelectedItem.ToString() #populate the var with the value you selected
$procResult=remove-item \\$computer\c$\Windows\System32\winevt\Logs\*.* | fl | out-string;
$outputBox.text=$procResult
                     } #end delLogs

Comment: function runCompliance {
$computer=$DropDownBox.SelectedItem.ToString() #populate the var with the value you selected
$procResult=$Baselines = Get-WmiObject -ComputerName $ComputerName -Namespace root\ccm\dcm -Class SMS_DesiredConfiguration
$Baselines | % { ([wmiclass]"\\$ComputerName\root\ccm\dcm:SMS_DesiredConfiguration").TriggerEvaluation($_.Name, $_.Version) };
$outputBox.text=$procResult
                     } #end cleanWinsxs

Comment: ############################################## end functions

############################################## Start drop down boxes

$DropDownBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.ComboBox
$DropDownBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(20,50) 
$DropDownBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(180,20) 
$DropDownBox.DropDownHeight = 200 
$Form.Controls.Add($DropDownBox)

Comment: $wksList=@(Get-ADComputer -Filter 'operatingsystem -like "*server*" -and enabled -eq "true"' ` -Properties Name | Sort-Object -Property Name | Select-Object -Property Name)

foreach ($wks in $wksList) {
                      $DropDownBox.Items.Add($wks.Name)
                              } #end foreach

############################################## end drop down boxes

############################################## Start text fields

Comment: $outputBox = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.TextBox 
$outputBox.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(10,150) 
$outputBox.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(565,200) 
$outputBox.MultiLine = $True 
$outputBox.ScrollBars = "Vertical" 
$Form.Controls.Add($outputBox) 

############################################## end text fields

Comment: ############################################## Start buttons

$Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(475,20) 
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,40) 
$Button.Text = "Ping" 
$Button.Add_Click({procInfo}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

Comment: $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(398,20) 
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(80,40) 
$Button.Text = "Delete Old Logs" 
$Button.Add_Click({delLogs}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

Comment: $Button = New-Object System.Windows.Forms.Button 
$Button.Location = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(310,20) 
$Button.Size = New-Object System.Drawing.Size(90,40) 
$Button.Text = "Run Compliance" 
$Button.Add_Click({runCompliance}) 
$Form.Controls.Add($Button)

Comment: ############################################## end buttons

$Form.Add_Shown({$Form.Activate()})
[void] $Form.ShowDialog()